# R.layout.mobile cannot be resolved in java class other than MainActivity.java

Tags: android

I added new xml file under res/layout/ directory.

The file is mobile.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:textSize="15px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I created new class ImageAdaptor.java under src\com\example\customadapter where my MainActivity.java is located. I can access R.layout.mobile in MainActivity.java. But i cannot access R.layout.mobile in ImageAdaptor.java. It shows mobile cannot be resolved or it is not a field.

Please help..................

Comment: post ur ImageAdaptor code?

Comment: try an `Eclipse clean` or at least show us how you're trying to use `R.layout.mobile` from `ImageAdaptor`

Comment: Chack the problems perspective from eclipse and check if it shows errors. Also check that your java class import the R from your package and not the andrid.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access layout file with out context of Activity because every layout file is attached with any of the activity.

For updating the Layout you should use Handler Thread. Pass the context from Activity to your ImageAdaptor.java.class then make Update Handler there from ImageAdaptor.java.

I hope its helpful to you.